# Figuring out cause of Graphical differences between ggplot and base R plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted my data in both base R and `ggplot` methods to see how the plots look different, and my graph from ggplot() form looks wrong. It should look like it does when I graph it in base R. Shown below is my base R code and my ggplot code, and the graphs that each produce.

Base R code:

em is though.

Comment: They are the same plots. The points are just connected in different orders. Use points to see that these plots are identical. Base plot connect lines based on the data order. ggplot connects via a sorted order.

Comment: Is there a way to get ggplot to connect them via order?

Comment: geom_path() 3char

Comment: I added `+ geom_path()` to the end of my ggplot code, and it makes it look incredibly weird and nothing like my base R plot.

Comment: Unless its supposed to be geom_path(aes(rhn, depth)) ?

Comment: You must have added geom_line and path. Skip the line.

Comment: Got it! If you submit an answer, I'll vote it as the solution since you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `geom_path()` instead of `geom_line()` to preserve the ordering of the dataset. This is documented in `?geom_line`